# How to edit a /etc/ssh text file as an owner

Tags: ssh, config.txt

I want to update a line in the sshd_config as this line is causing termination to any [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) connection. I **have** to edit it manually not using the command window, so I opened the text file and updated it, but I can't as I should be the owner to have this permission. How do I open it as an owner?

When typing `sudo nano etc/ssh/sshd_config`, it opens a new empty file, not the one I want to edit.

Comment: you need 'sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config' - note the first forward slash, this way you go from root aka '/'

Answer (score 2):

Nano will show you a blank file when the file you wish to open does not exist. Saving the file (Ctrl-X) will create that file you opened.

Your command to open etc/ssh/sshd_conf is relative to your current directory. For example, if your current directory is /home/pi, you are opening a file at /home/pi/etc/ssh/sshd_conf, which does not exist thereby showing you a blank file.

You should have added an initial / before the etc to refer to a file relative to the highest level directory or the root of the drive:

> sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_conf